# Can the European Commission be sued if it doesn't follow parliamentary initiative proposed by the European Parliament and fails to justify it?

Tags: european-union, international-law

Can the European Commission be taken to court if it doesn't follow parliamentary initiative proposed by the European Parliament and fails to justify it adequately? The European Parliament have the right to invite the European Commission to present a legislative proposal even though the European Commission has a near monopoly on legislative initiative in the European Union. I was told that it's a near monopoly because the European Commission has to justify any refusal to take a legislative proposal from the European Parliament and outright reject it, so does the European Parliament have the authority to bring the European Commission to court, meaning that the sovereign immunity doesn't apply in this case, or does the European Commission has a de-facto monopoly on legislative initiative in the European Union meaning that it can reject any legislative proposal from any entity?